# Replaced my rim with a wider one - will my tire still fit?

Tags: road-bike, rims, puncture, tyre-width

I was running Shimano RS on my road bike (not sure the width) and switched to Bontrager Paradigm Comp. A sticker says 622x19 - I'm guessing 19 is the rim width. It's definitely wider than my old wheel. The tire is 25 mm.

On the old wheel, I had zero flats in over 3500 km - same tire and tube models. Since the replacement, I had two flats in about 100 km travelled. After the first one, I figured I must have pinched it, but I was super careful with the replacement and it happened again.

If it matters, I'm quite a heavy rider. My guess is that there is just a risk of a pinch when I hit a bump.

I'm wondering if my tire is just too narrow for the new rim? I can probably still return the wheel (although I'm happy with it other than the flats) - or should I just swap my tire for a 28 mm one?

Comment: @ojs thanks, not sure why I wasn't able to find that, it does answer my question!

Comment: No problem :) It's a bit difficult to find if you don't know the exact phrase to search for.